# Как правильно использовать mock из Mockito

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, mockito

Есть класс который я хочу протестировать, но когда я использую `mock` у меня не получается нормальной замены, то есть результирующий метод в классе `getWinner()` не возвращает ожидаемого значения . Когда я использую реальный объект то все работает. В чем я не правильно использую `mock`?

Сам класс:

```
public class TicTacToe implements TicTacToeStart {
    // хранит партии которые можно будет сыграть в процессе игры
    private ArrayList<Play> games = new ArrayList<>();
    // хранит объекты игроков которые победили
    private ArrayList<Subject> winners = new ArrayList<>();
    //имя единственного победителя набравшего 5 побед
    private String winner;

    // for test
    void setGames(ArrayList games) {
        this.games = games;
    }

    // инициализирует объеты партий
    public void createGames() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            this.games.add(
                    new Game());
        }
    }

    // возвращает имя победителя
    @Override
    public String getWinner() {
        return this.winner;
    }

    // зацикливает игры до 5 побед
    @Override
    public void start() {
        int count = 0;
        while (checkWinner().equals("") && count < games.size()) {
            Play game = this.games.get(count);
            game.choiceSide();
            game.loopMove();
            Subject winner = game.initWinner();
            if (!winner.getName().equals("nobody")) {
                this.winners.add(winner);
            }
            count++;
        }
        this.winner = checkWinner();
    }

    // проверяет кто победил 5 раз и возвращает имя победителя
    private String checkWinner() {
        int user = 0, bot = 0;
        for (Subject winner : winners) {
            if ("user".equals(winner.getName())) {
                user++;
                if (user == 5) return "user";
            }

            if ("bot".equals(winner.getName())) {
                bot++;
                if (bot == 5) return "bot";
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
    @Test
    public void whenThen() {

        // подготовка
        StubInput input = new StubInput();
        input.setAnswersStr(new String[] {
                "I", "y",
                "I", "y",
                "I", "y",
                "I", "y",
                "I", "y"});

        input.setAnswersNum(new int[] {
                1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2,
                1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2,
                1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2,
                1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2,
                1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2});

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.setInput(input);
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setDialogs(dialog);

        ArrayList<Play> games = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            games.add(game);
        }

        TicTacToe ticTac = new TicTacToe();
        TicTacToe spy = spy(ticTac);
        spy.setGames(games);
        spy.start();

        // действие
        String result = spy.getWinner();

        // проверка что метод вызвался и что вернул что надо но 
        // я хочу как то проверить это-же только без строчки
        // spy.setGames(games); и этого огромного стаба
        verify(spy).getWinner();
        assertEquals(result, "bot");
    }
```

Comment: Моки нужны для того, чтобы подменять зависимости, а не работать с непосредственно тестируемым классом. Скорее всего, мокито просто подменяет все методы в моке на null-возвращающие заглушки, чтобы мок в тесте ненароком не вызвал сайд-эффекты. Вам абсолютно точно, стопроцентно не нужно мокать здесь ваш класс.

Comment: Извиняюсь не тот тест схватил поменял код.

Comment: пожалуйста опишите словами, что именно вы тестируете. не забывайте, что юнит тест должен тестировать только маленькую (изолированную) часть функциональности. хороший юнит тесто состоит из 3 частей: подготовка, действие и проверка. выделите эти части  в вашем тесте.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman (и очистка(teardown))

Comment: (и очистка(teardown)) а это что?

Comment: @Etki в юнит тесте ее обычно нет, либо она делается на уровне test case.

Comment: Вот добавил комментарии

Comment: @MikhailVaysman это xunit-стандарт - setup, exercise, verify, teardown.

Comment: Ну вот последний пункт это наверно при тестировании чего-то что гербеч коллектор не съест... тут мне кажется нечего очищать.

Comment: @Etki я руководствуюсь в основном опытом, а не стандартами. в большинстве тестов teardown часть не нужна.

Comment: @Павел _проверка что метод вызвался и что вернул что надо_ - это надо разбить на 2 теста

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я про реальные фазы теста, а не то, что пишется руками. Теоретически тест может состоять и из одного exercise (проверка на отсутствие исключений в сценарии) с подразумеваемым verify (подразумевается, что исключение не было выброшено), но фазы остаются. Просто сейчас человек выучит три, а через год с изумлением обнаружит четвертую.

Comment: >>>проверка что метод вызвался и что вернул что надо - это надо разбить на 2 теста<<<- ок понял спасибо. А как же мне все-таки без сеттера обойтись?

Comment: @Etki я ведь не говорил про фазы. я не говорил про стандарт. я высказал свое мнение. оно может быть ошибочным. не вижу в этом ничего страшного.

Comment: @Павел на мой взгляд у вас проблемы в архитектуре приложения и вы "затыкаете" дыры при помощи сеттеров/геттеров. попробуйте отступить назад и подумать над архитектурой. попробуйте ее нарисовать или описать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему ощущению вы мокаете не то.

Во первых, какой смысл этой проверки?

```
String result = spy.getWinner();
verify(spy).getWinner();
```

Она не несет никакого смысла.

Во вторых, если вы хотите проверить возвращаемый результат, то мокать надо объект `Game` что бы получилось примерно так:

```
Game game = mock(Game.class);
when(game.initWinner()).thenReturn(/*объект Subject с именем bot*/);

ArrayList<Play> games = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    games.add(game);
}

//запускаем игру
TicTacToe ticTac = new TicTacToe();
ticTac.setGames(games);
ticTac.start();

//проверяем результат
String result = spy.getWinner();
//сюда ещё можно добавить проверку вызовов метода на объекте game
assertEquals(result, "bot");
```

Ну и потом отдельным тестом можно протестировать объект `Game`, в частности его метод `initWinner()` на то, что он возвращает нужный `Subject`